# How to setup integration tests for ASP.NET MVC 5 and Web Api 2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, integration-testing

I am writing integrations tests for my .NET web applications right now. It is going well in general. I found clear documentation that explains how to do this. For example, I am using `WebApplicationFactory` with .NET Core to [test my ASP .NET Core projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1). I also wrote integration tests for my WCF applications. [This is how I did it](http://geekswithblogs.net/ballhaus/archive/2009/12/21/integration-testing-wcf-services-with-unity.aspx). In all these situations, I was able test without starting the applications [and measure the code coverage in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/using-code-coverage-to-determine-how-much-code-is-being-tested?view=vs-2019).

However, for my .NET Framework projects (MVC 5 en Web Api 2), it is not clear to me how to do similar integration tests for like I wrote for .NET Core and WCF. I found [a test Framework](https://github.com/i-e-b/MvcIntegrationTestFramework#usage) but unfortunately that does not target recent versions Web Api and it has not been maintained for years. Moreover, it is also not stable when using MVC 5. So what to do now? I just need similar tests for my ASP .NET web applications too. How to make such tests?

My tests need to work on a machine with windows with .NET Framework. So I **don't** need any explanations for .NET Core.

Comment: The solution we used back then was to start web api in-process on a random port in a simlar way how TestServer does it. And use real client and real http requests. If that sounds reasonable enough for you I can try to reproduce how we did it.

Comment: Does [This](https://www.strathweb.com/2015/05/integration-testing-asp-net-5-asp-net-mvc-6-applications/) help?

Comment: There isn't an ASP.NET MVC 6 for .NET Framework. Could you link to the version you're using? (ASP.NET MVC 6 was renamed ASP.NET Core).

Comment: Part of the reason you may not be getting any answers is that your title and the words you use aren't clear. There is no ASP.NET MVC 6 for .NET Framework. ASP.NET MVC "6" became ASP.NET Core MVC 1.0. Which version of .NET Core are you using?  Do you have continuous integration set up? If so, what environment is it? (windows? linux?)

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Thanks for the feedback. There was some misunderstanding on my side when describing the version numbers. That's now fixed.

Comment: @Hintham Thanks for the link. It will be helpfull for my .NET Core projects but it does not help me for .NET Framework. Your link describes how to setup the project.json file. That does not exist in .NET Framework.

Comment: You just need an in memory owin server. Check this one : https://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/asp-net-web-api-integration-testing-with-in-memory-hosting/ . Pease note that there is no nice and easy way before net core. Hope helps, Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

The .NET framework equivalent to the `WebApplicationFactory` is the Owin Test server.

You have to install the NuGet package `Microsoft.Owin.Testing`

```
using (var server = TestServer.Create<OwinStartup>()){
    using (var client = new HttpClient(server.Handler))
    {
    //Make API Calls here
    }
}
```

There is a good example here https://blog.jcorioland.io/archives/2014/04/01/using-owin-to-test-your-web-api-controllers.html